# Ionic 4 how to navigate from tab page to non-tab page keeping tab?

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, ionic4

In Ionic 4, I have an application with a tabs ( 5 pages Home, Search, Map, Info, Tarif)
From Search page i navigate to Detail page but i want to keeping the tab menu on Detail page.
I don't know if is possible ?

How do you configure the route ?
This is my:
 `app-routing.module.ts`

```
`const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'map', loadChildren: './map/map.module#MapPageModule' },
  { path: 'search', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchPageModule' },
  { path: 'station', loadChildren: './station/station.module#StationPageModule' },
  { path: 'info', loadChildren: './info/info.module#InfoPageModule' },
  { path: 'tarif', loadChildren: './tarif/tarif.module#TarifPageModule' }
];`

and my `tabs.router.module.ts`

`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        outlet: 'search',
        component: SearchPage
      },
      {
        path: 'map',
        outlet: 'map',
        component: MapPage
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        outlet: 'info',
        component: InfoPage
      },
      {
        path: 'tarif',
        outlet: 'tarif',
        component: TarifPage
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];`

The station page must be a child page of Search page ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You do that using this setting in `app.module.ts` file.

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    tabsHideOnSubPages: false
})
```

Comment: it seems to me that this option does not exist in ionic 4

Answer (score 0):

As ionic tabs template have this provisioning to push any detail page with in the same tab navigation stack.

So you can do it like below to push your Detail view in same Search tab section.

```
this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, { detailId: detailData.id });
```

by doing this you can push your detail page into same Tab page.

Hope this will helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the Detail page a child of the "tabs" routes. This works without displaying an icon for that page in the tab icon bar.

Add an entry into the "children" array in `tabs.router.module.ts`:

```
 {
    path: 'detail',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '../detail/detail.module#DetailPageModule'
      }
    ]
 },
```

Then you may navigate to `/tabs/detail`, for example in a ion-button or similar by `[routerLink]="['/tabs/detail']"`.

If you like, you may also define a redirect route in your `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
 { path: 'detail', redirectTo: '/tabs/detail' }
```

A drawback of this solution is, that the tab bar icon of your "Search" page will not be coloured when the "Detail" page is displayed. But this may be solved by additional CSS formatting.